# Clojure: Unable to find static field

Tags: clojure

Given the following piece of code:

```
(map Integer/parseInt ["1" "2" "3" "4"])
```

Why do I get the following exception unless I wrap `Integer/parseInt` in an anonymous function and call it manually (`#(Integer/parseInt %)`)?

```
clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find static field: parseInt in class java.lang.Integer
```

Comment: in addition to the excellent answers you have already - Clojure is a fairly thin abstraction over the jvm, and there is no such thing as a first class method, so a method can't be an argument to a Clojure function. That is, on a byte code level, a method can't be an argument.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

the documentation on java interop says the following:

> The preferred idiomatic forms for accessing field or method members
>   are given above. The instance member form works for both fields and
>   methods. The instanceField form is preferred for fields and required
>   if both a field and a 0-argument method of the same name exist. They
>   all expand into calls to the dot operator (described below) at
>   macroexpansion time. The expansions are as follows:
>   ...
>   (Classname/staticMethod
>   args*) ==> (. Classname staticMethod args*) Classname/staticField ==>
>   (. Classname staticField)

so you should remember, that `Class/fieldName` is just a sugar for getting a static **field**, neither static **method call**, nor **reference to the static method** (java method is not a clojure function really), so there is no static field `parseInt` in `Integer class`, while `(Class/fieldName arg)` calls a static **method**, they are two totally different operations, using the similar sugary syntax.

so when you do `(map #(Integer/parseInt %) ["1" "2" "3" "4"])` it expands to

`(map #(. Integer parseInt %) ["1" "2" "3" "4"])`

(you can easily see it yourself with macroexpansion),

and `(map Integer/parseInt ["1" "2" "3"])` expands to

`(map (. Integer parseInt) ["1" "2" "3"])`

It fails when it is trying to get a field (which you think is getting a reference to a method).

Answer (score 6):

`Integer/parseInt` is a static method of `Integer` class, not a clojure function. Each clojure function is compiled to java class which implements `clojure.lang.IFn` interface. `map` expects clojure function (which implements `IFn` interface) as a first argument, however, `Integer/parseInt` is not.

You can check that in the clojure repl.

```
user=> (type map)
clojure.core$map
user=> (type Integer)
java.lang.Class
user=> (type Integer/parseInt)

CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find static field: parseInt in class java.lang.Integer, compiling:(/private/var/folders/p_/psdvlp_12sdcxq07pp07p_ycs_v5qf/T/form-init4110003279275246905.clj:1:1)

user=> (defn f [] 1)
#'user/f
user=> (type f)
user$f
user=> (type #(1))
user$eval9947$fn__9948
```

Perhaps reading [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708516/what-type-is-a-function) will help you understand what is going on.

Comment: Thinking in terms of Clojure (rather than Java implementation), you would say that the function argument to the `map` function is the first argument. Bit confusing to hear it called the second argument.

Comment: @ChrisMurphy You're correct. It was a mistake. I updated the post.

Answer (score 3):

You might prefer to do it without the Java interop:

`(map read-string ["1" "2"])`

or for a more safe variant:

`(map clojure.edn/read-string ["1" "2"])`

I personally prefer to minimize the use of Java as much as possible in Clojure code.

As for why you can't just pass the Java function, because `map` expects a function in Clojure, not a function in Java.

Comment: `read-string` is almost always a bad idea. documentation says: "Note that read-string can execute code (controlled by *read-eval*),
and as such should be used only with trusted sources.
 For data structure interop use clojure.edn/read-string". try this one in your repl `(read-string "#=(spit \"./filename.sh\" \"evil code\")")` . As you almost always use data conversion for external data, `read-string` is highly unsafe here