# Rounding to the nearest digit in list in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I am trying to get the rounded off version of a list of numerics in Clojure.

For e.g. `(Math/round 10.5)` gives me `11` as the answer which is fine. However, I try a similar approach using 'apply' - `(apply Math/round (list 1.2 2.1 3.4))` which gives me an error. I was expecting `(1 2 3)` as the output.

How to get a rounded off output from a list of numbers?

Comment: @JaredSmith: I am a newbie to Clojure. I was blindly following this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28551000/what-is-the-best-way-to-round-numbers-in-clojure

Comment: Nevermind my earlier comment, it's the same interop for both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `map`. Note that you'll have to wrap the call to `Math/round` in an anonymous function: see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35199808/clojure-unable-to-find-static-field) for the reason why.

```
(map #(Math/round %) (list 1.1 2.2 3.9)) ; '(1 2 4)
```

The problem with your approach (which was actually not a bad guess) is that Java's `Math/round` isn't variadic: it just takes a single argument. Calling `apply` that way is the same as saying

```
(Math/round 1.2 2.1 3.4)
```

Which will fail to compile.